# pass data from view controller to tabbarcontroller

Tags: swift, xcode

I start out in a view controller and I want to segue to a tab bar controller at the press of a button.

```
 @IBAction func goToReplyProfile(_ sender: Any) {
        let storyBoard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
        let vc = storyBoard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "CommentTabBarController") as! TTabBarViewController

        self.present (vc, animated: false, completion: nil)
    }
```

Which segues perfectly. However, I attempted to pass data to the first view controller of the tab bar by doing this

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if let vc = (segue.destination as? UITabBarController)?.viewControllers?.first as? CommentProfileViewController {

        let testing = "practice"
        vc.Author = testing

    }
}
```

My issue is that in the destined view controller,  I included a print statement to see if the data is passed but the app crashes on the print statement.

```
print(Author! + "should print out testing")
```

Comment: `self.present` isn't using a `segue`, so `prepare(for segue: sender:)` will not be called.  You need to trigger a segue with `performSegue(withIdentifier: "segueName", sender: self)` to start a segue.  The segue must already be wired in the Storyboard and have the identifier you use assigned to it.

Comment: ... or pass the data to your viewController in `goToReplyProfile` before calling `self.present`.

Answer (score 0):

This line

```
 self.present (vc, animated: false, completion: nil)
```

has no thing to do with prepareForSegue and it actually doesn't run your code in it , hence nil author that causes the crash , what you really need is using `performSegue(withIdentifier` that calls prepare

//

the problem is here you send self as a sender

```
 performSegue(withIdentifier: "FirstVC", sender: self)
```

and here you cast as `IndexPath` which for sure will fail

```
if let indexPath = sender as? IndexPath
```

Comment: i made changes to my question

Comment: i changed the sender and still nothing

Comment: prepare function that is not in the edit [in your question ]is correct as the destination is the tabbar no the first VC

Comment: also what the value you changed the sender to , attach whole code

Comment: this **let indexPath = sender as? IndexPath** is wrong as sender is a UIButton , also do you have a table that you want to send it's selected index

Comment: so basically I have a table view and when I click on a button I want to segue to a profile that of the button that I clicked. My segue is to the tabbarcontroller and I have never segued to a tabbarcontroller that is why I am having trouble

Comment: *New edit* ok now in the override I am able to print out the print statement. I am also trying to send data to another view controller but when I send it and include a print statement, it returns nil